# Customizing html file input tag

Tags: html, css

I want to customize the text that appears after the html file input button i.e., Choose Files.
[Query Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSpOz.png)

I am trying to style the default html file input tag and i am able to style the button part (i.e., Choose File button) but i don't know how to style the text (which says No file chosen). Can anyone help me in the same.

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the appearance of the text that appears after the HTML file input button (Choose Files) can be achieved using HTML, CSS, and a bit of JaVaScript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    /* Basic styling for the file input container */
    .file-input-container {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    /* Styling for the actual file input */
    .file-input {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Styling for the custom text that appears after file input */
    .custom-text {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 8px 12px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- File input container -->
<div class="file-input-container">
  <!-- Actual file input -->
  <input type="file" class="file-input" id="myFileInput" onchange="updateCustomText()">
  <!-- Custom text that appears after file input -->
  <label for="myFileInput" class="custom-text">Choose Files</label>
</div>

<script>
  // Function to update the custom text based on selected files
  function updateCustomText() {
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('myFileInput');
    const customText = document.querySelector('.custom-text');

    if (fileInput.files.length === 1) {
      customText.textContent = fileInput.files[0].name;
    } else if (fileInput.files.length > 1) {
      customText.textContent = fileInput.files.length + ' files selected';
    } else {
      customText.textContent = 'Choose Files';
    }
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As far as I understood from your code you're hiding the button part of html file input and trying to style the text but i didn't want it. I want to style the text also and i don't want to hide the button part. Also i don't want to make use of another button and totally hide the file input and then click that using js.